# How to run tomcat service with java -server option?

Tags: java, tomcat

I am using tomcat as a window service and I want to turn on the java -server option on for the jvm. I tried to do this by putting a -server option into the java tab in Tomcat6w application (the tomcat monitor application). However, this didn't work, Tomcat wasn't started, looklike Tomcat6w expects only D or X options for the jvm. Anyone knows how can I put the -server option in this case?

Answer (score 3):

Install JDK and configure the service (doubleclick Tomcat tray icon and open the *Java* tab) to use `jdk/jre/bin/server/jvm.dll` instead of (default) `jre/bin/client/jvm.dll`.

Answer (score 0):

or

make sure you have jdk with server jvm.dll

then

service remove tomcat
service install tomcat

where tomcat is the name of the service

if you dont know it find using

sc query