# Java Robot mouseMove not working when tomcat is running as Windows service

Tags: java, eclipse, windows, tomcat, selenium

I am trying to run an automation script using Selenium and in this script Robot class's mouseMove method has been used to move mouse cursor to a specific location. When I run this script from eclipse as a Java application or using tomcat (this script is a part of larger framework, which is deployed on tomcat), it is working fine.

But if I run tomcat as a windows service, the same code is not working. There is no error in the server logs, but the mouse cursor is not moving. Please let me know if anyone knows a resolution for this issue.

Following are the lines of code from the script, which produce no result when tomcat is running as a windows service:

```
WebElement element = driver.findElement(By.id("headerForm:j_id26"));
Actions builder = new Actions(driver); 
builder.click(element).build().perform(); 
Point mousePt = element.getLocation();

int x = (int) mousePt.getX(); 
int y = (int) mousePt.getY(); 
Robot robot = new Robot(); 
robot.mouseMove(x+100, y+110); 
robot.mousePress(InputEvent.BUTTON1_MASK); 
robot.mouseRelease(InputEvent.BUTTON1_MASK);
```

Comment: How about posting that automation script for us.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to run tomcat service with java -server option?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3274351/how-to-run-tomcat-service-with-java-server-option)

Comment: I tried with server jvm as well, but same result.